# invoking javascript on a click of label

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview and inside the gridview, I have a label and when the user clicks on that label, I invoke a javascript function. I passw few values from that label to javascript function. If the values has apsotrphe in it. It generates an error and does not invke javascript function. Below is my code.

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <label style="text-decoration: underline" onclick="javascript:GetSelectedRow('<%# Eval("ID") %>','<%# Eval("systempath") %>','','',1);"><%#Eval("ID") %></label> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and the javascript function is

```
function GetSelectedRow(id, systempath, x, x, rowIndex) { 

    debugger; 
    var label = document.getElementById('<%=lbl_ID.ClientID %>'); 

    label.innerText = mclid + "|" + systempath; 
    document.getElementById('<%=hdnlblID.ClientID %>').value = id + "|" + systempath; 

    return false; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<label style="text-decoration: underline" onclick="javascript:GetSelectedRow('<%# Eval("ID") %>','<%# Eval("systempath").ToString().Replace("'", @"\'"); %>','','',1);"><%#Eval("ID") %></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use single quotes around the ID, you'll need to escape and apostrophe:

```
var label = document.getElementById('<%=lbl_ID.ClientID.Replace("'", "\'") %>');
```